# Как порезать и склеить видео Android?

Tags: android, видео

У меня есть три видео, необходимо их склеить между собой. К примеру, с первого видео взять 3 секунды, потом со второго его 4,5 секунду и завершить все последними секундами третьего видео.

Мне нужно не приложение, в котором реализована такая возможность, а подсказка, как программно это реализовать. (Пример кода)

Как можно обрезать и склеить видео? Возможно кто-то сталкивался.

Comment: @pavlofff Возможно я его задала некорректно, но мне нужно не приложение, в котором реализована такая возможность, а подсказка, как программно  это реализовать. (Пример кода).

Comment: Есть библиотека mp4parser и проект на [github](https://github.com/lassana/continuous-audiorecorder), там представлена реализация аудиозаписи, в которой можно делать паузу и потом дописывать, но используется эта библиотека и работа проходит с mp4 форматом. Думаю если копнуть глубже, то там можно будет посмотреть реализацию склеивания видео.

Comment: А лучше сразу на [mp4parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser) смотреть

Comment: А вы представьте что у вас не 3 видео а 3 строки. Вам нужно отрезать от первой строки первые 3 символа, от второй 4, от третей последние 5 и склеить их в одну строку. Справились бы с таким заданием? Известно что строка это массив чаров, то видео это массив ..., массив чего ищете в спецификации по формату. Конечно это все абстрактно, но просто вам нужно сузить поиск, и не задаваться как обрезать видео а как обрезать то из чего оно состоит. Это из серии как это реализовать:-)

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish Осталось всего ничего - узнать из чего состоит видео..

Comment: А вы что хотели, порезать видео как колбасу?

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish Не улавливаю Вашей иронии.
Большое спасибо за ответы и советы!

Answer (score 1):

Как вам советуют - попробуйте mp4parser, начните с этого примера: 
https://github.com/vicmns/mp4parser-android-test/blob/master/mp4parserAppTest/src/com/vicmns/mp4parserapptest/MainActivity.java

```
            trimmVideo1 = new TrimmVideo(workingPath + "/первое видео.mp4",0, 3).execute();
            trimmVideo2 = new TrimmVideo(workingPath + "/второе видео.mp4",4, 1).execute();
                mergeVideos = new MergeVideos(workingPath, videosToMerge).execute();
```

Сложнее конечно, так как вам надо будет сделать цепочку AsyncTask и принимать из одного в другой результаты...